# generators for asynchronous iteration of large file

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, generator, postgis, idioms

Say I have a function called `openShapeFile`, which reads a file, and produces a Promise which wraps source object which has a `read` function, which is returns a Promise which wraps the actual value in the Shapefile, and has a `.done` boolean value which can be used to tell if the end of the file has been reached.

In effect, the `shapefile.open` from here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/shapefile

If I now want to read a file into a database, I can say:

```
openShapeFile(`shapefile.shp`).then((source) => source.read()
  .then(function log(result) {
    if (result.done) {
      return
    } else {
      let query = `INSERT INTO geodata(geometry, id, featcode) VALUES(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('${
        JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, result.value.geometry, {coordinates: result.value.geometry.coordinates.map(JSON.stringify)}))
      }'), '${
        result.value.properties.ID
      }', ${
        result.value.properties.FEATCODE
      });`
      query = query.split('"[[').join('[[').split(']]"').join(']]')
      return pool.query(query).then((result) => {
        return source.read().then(log)
      })
      }
      })).then(() => console.log(dirCount)).catch(err => 'Problem here')))
```

This just about works, but has a recursive Promise (weird)

So as an exercise and/or to see if it would produce more clarity, I decided to rewrite it into generators, producing something like so:

```
function *insertQuery(query) {
    const result = pool.query(query)
    return result
  }

  const shapeFileGenerator = co.wrap(function* (source) {
    while (true) {
      const result = yield source.read()
      if (result.done) {
        return yield {}
      } else {
        let query = `INSERT INTO geodata(geometry, id, featcode) VALUES(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('${
          JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, result.value.geometry, {coordinates: result.value.geometry.coordinates.map(JSON.stringify)}))
        }'), '${
          result.value.properties.ID
        }', ${
          result.value.properties.FEATCODE
        });`
        query = query.split('"[[').join('[[').split(']]"').join(']]')
        yield* insertQuery(query)
      }
    }
  })
openShapeFile(`shapefile.shp`).then((source) => {
  const s = shapeFileGenerator(source)
})))
```

Now this works! It reads all of the data! 
However, I kind of hate the infinite loop, and I never call .next directly. How can I rework this? What would be an idiomatic way to do something like this with generators? It seems like I *should* be able to write a proper generator with `s.next()` resulting in a `source.read()`?

Comment: DONT use generators with promises! Use `async`/`await`!

Comment: "*I never call .next directly.*" - the `co` library does that for you. Why would you want to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would write

```
async function readFileToDB(filename) {
    const source = await openShapeFile(filename);
    for (let {value, done} = await source.read(); !done; {value, done} = await source.read()) {
        const query = `INSERT INTO geodata(geometry, id, featcode) VALUES(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('${
            JSON.stringify(value.geometry)
        }'), '${
            value.properties.ID
        }', ${
            value.properties.FEATCODE
        });`
        const result = await pool.query(query);
    }
    console.log(dirCount);
}
readFileToDB(`shapefile.shp`).catch(err => console.error('Problem here', err));
```

tough I don't think there's anything wrong with the recursive solution either.

> It seems like I should be able to write a proper generator with `s.next()` resulting in a `source.read()`?

No, generators are synchronous. You might want to have a look at the [async iteration proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration) though.

Answer (score -1):

You can code your logic as if it was synchronous, and execute via sequential executor [nsynjs](https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs). Below is slightly modified working example tested on [this file](https://cdn.rawgit.com/matplotlib/basemap/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/UScounties.shp):

main.js:

```
var nsynjs = require('nsynjs');
var shapefile = require('shapefile');

function synchrobousCode(shapefile /*, pool */) {
    var source = shapefile.open('UScounties.shp').data;
    var result = source.read().data;
    while(result && !result.done) {
        var query = "INSERT INTO geodata(geometry, id, featcode) VALUES('" +
            JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, result.value.geometry, {coordinates: result.value.geometry.coordinates.map(JSON.stringify)})) +
            "'), '" +
            result.value.properties.ID +
            "'," +
            result.value.properties.FEATCODE +
            "')";
        console.log(query.length);
        // uncomment line below to sequentially insert to the DB
        // var queryRes = pool.query(query).data;
        result = source.read().data;
    }
}

nsynjs.run(synchrobousCode,null,shapefile /*, pool */ ,function () {
    console.log('all done');
})
```

Nsynjs will automatically detect if some function call returns promise. If yes, it will wait for promise to resolve, put result of it to `data` property, and only then continue to next expression.